# JavaScript. Объявление неизменяемого метода для обьекта

Tags: javascript, node.js, инспекция-кода

Пытаюсь реализовать обьект в котором может быть произвольное количество свойств и функция-метод которая получает входящий параметр строку и проверяет есть ли свойство с таким именем. Свойства и метод нельзя переопределять, удалять и к обьекту нельзя добавлять новую функциональность. Нужно мне это для подобия энума.

```
var SomeObj = {};

Object.defineProperties(SomeObj, {
    prop1: {
        value: 1,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true

    },
    isAllowed: {
        value: function (type) {
            return this.hasOwnProperty(type);
        },
        writable: false,
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true
    }
});
Object.preventExtensions(SomeObj);
```

Смущает то что в статьях я не встречал такой синтаксис (`value: function () {}`) , кроме того автодополнение пхпшторма на обьекте `SomeObj` метод `isAllowed` показывает как свойство(без скобок в конце которые нужно вручную доставлять) что в принципе не удивительно так как он как свойство и обьявлен, но это не очевидно. Одним словом есть ли другой способ обьявить метод для обекта который нельзя впоследствии переопределить.

Comment: `defineProperty` два подхода, через value, и через get/set: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Смотрели в сторону https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, Вы ищите [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) или [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)?

Из MDN: Метод Object.freeze() замораживает объект: это значит, что он предотвращает добавление новых свойств к объекту, удаление старых свойств из объекта и изменение существующих свойств или значения их атрибутов перечисляемости, настраиваемости и записываемости.

Answer (score 0):

Только внутри объекта определить приватные свойства и методы через var.